# Does anybody have any experience with SSEPlus?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, assembly

[SSEPlus](http://sseplus.sourceforge.net) is an open source library from AMD for unified handling of [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) processor extensions.

I'm considering to use this library for my next small project and would like to know, if anybody have experience with it? Can I use it on Intel machines? Any performance issues in comparison to direct SSE calls? Any issues on 64bit machines? What other projects than [Framewave](http://framewave.sourceforge.net) use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it on Intel machines too.

Performance should not differ except that it adds the checks about supported processor features which might cost a little.